# Same static route configuration on two different interface (Centos7)

Tags: routing

I'm planning to set-up a server, running centos 7, that is connected to three networks with three eth ports. Those three networks belong to 10.0.0.0/8. I configured 10.0.0.0/8 into two eth ports (static route). The other one port is for the default route. I know that there would be a routing conflict between the two eth ports.

Is there a possible solution to resolve this routing issue in such a way that I'm not going to breakdown the 10.0.0.0/8?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that these 10.0.0.0/8 networks are two *different* an incompatible 10.0.0.0/8 networks? Then, no, you can't solve this — not without a lot of hacks (NAT? network namespaces?), anyway.

The routing table needs to be told to direct packets that go to 10.0.0.0/8 one way or the other (or load balanced over both, or similar). Period. It cannot guess which one the packet "should" go to.

One lesson to be learned here is that unless you have an awfully large network, try not to claim all of 10.0.0.0/8 for it. That way there is a chance that when you need to connect a node to two of these networks at the same time, each network will have taken a small piece of 10.0.0.0/8 and with luck the pieces won't overlap and everything will be easy.